# P.notify like message with variable message

Tags: notifications, dialog, xpages, xpages-ssjs

in an Xpage , I'm looking for a message box like p.notify that gives a personalised message that fade's in and out automatically in my onclick of a button event.

in client side I put : `$.pnotify({ pnotify_title: 'Test',pnotify_text: 'personalised message'});`
Which works , but how do I put a personalised text in it from for example a viewScope

in server side I put : `view.postScript("$.pnotify({ pnotify_title: 'Test',pnotify_text: 'personalised message'});");` Which gives an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at Function.pnotify (jquery.pnotify.min.js:37)
    at demo.xsp:306

So my question : How can I put a personlised message (from for example a viewScope into the client side script , or is there a way to make my server side script to work or is there another way to get the same result ( I don't think there's a way to autoclose xpages dialogs after some time?)

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, however I use BootAlert, by Michael Smith which I think is great. It can be used both client and server side, and DOES have autoclose functionality so might be worth checking out? Very easy to setup and use........ https://xpage.me/2015/02/10/boot-your-alerts-in-the-with-bootalert/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the a clientside event of any XPages control you can add serverside code, for example:

```
<xp:button
    value="Show message"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        $.pnotify({ 
          pnotify_title: 'Test',
          pnotify_text: '#{javascript:viewScope.yourVar}'
        });]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Does that work in your situation?